# How can I route messages from Intermedia Exchange to Office 365 if they share the same domain?

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, microsoft-office-365

I would like to route messages from Intermedia Exchange to Office 365 where both environments share the same domain. (`example.com`)

To complicate this situation, the domain `example.com` is also hosted in-house on an internal exchange server. (3 Exchange hosting environments total)

**Background**

1 year ago we moved one business unit to Office 365. The rest were left on premise. I used the hybrid configuration wizard to configure the integration.  As a result the secondary SMTP address `example.mail.onmicrosoft.com` was added to all users.  This address (with a special send connector) allows O365 users to email the on premise users.

We are in the process of moving other business units to the Intermedia solution.  For this, we added a secondary SMTP address of `mig.example.com` to assist in the mail routing for on premise and Intermedia users.

The problem I'm seeing is that an Intermedia message routes

1. From their server, to an "onmicrosoft.com" / outlook server via a connector (good)
2. From MSFT to on premise (bad)
3. From on-premise back to MSFT (bad)

All in all, this is about 11 hops, and is unnecessary.

**Attempts to solve**

When we tried to add the Intermedia IP addresses to the connectors created by the Hybrid wizard, I get this error:

[image]

When we create a new "partner" connector on the o365 side, we have no routing improvement.

What are some different ways we can continue to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please ignore the "configuration conflict note. The upper error appears when the conflicting connector is removed.